# How to remove cgi-bin from my c panel?

Tags: cpanel, cgi-bin

When I visit my own domain site every time I seen same notice. I already delete file from my C panel and again again upload but every time seen same notice. What should I do to remove this **Index Of/ CGI-BIN** notice. Need help eagerly...

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a default folder that is being created for each domain that you add in your cPanel account, it's present for legacy reasons (some applications still use cgi).

> I already delete file from my C panel and again again upload but every
>   time seen same notice

- If you have deleted the folder and you're still seeing it on your requests it is possible that your browser have cached the content. **Try clearing your browser's cache and access the site again.**

> What should I do to remove this **Index Of/ CGI-BIN** notice. Need help
>   eagerly...

- Index Of is the default behavior of your http server - Apache httpd. It lists all directories/files that are currently present in the folder.

If you wish to hide the content from being displayed you can

**Place an index file like index.html or index.php**

**Create an .htaccess file** with the following code inside it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

*Note: If you have an index file created it will be loaded instead of the directory listing being shown, if you don't - you will send a 403 response back.*